# finbugs Error constructing methodGen

Tags: java, findbugs, bcel

I have very strange issue with `findbugs`:

```
Error constructing methodGen
org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid method signature: !+Lsome/packag/and/SomeClass
    org.apache.bcel.classfile.Utility.typeOfSignature(Utility.java:1012)
    org.apache.bcel.generic.Type.getType(Type.java:181)
    org.apache.bcel.generic.MethodGen.&amp;lt;init&amp;gt;(MethodGen.java:258)         edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.bcel.MethodGenFactory.analyze(MethodGenFactory.java:90)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.bcel.MethodGenFactory.analyze(MethodGenFactory.java:41)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.analyzeMethod(AnalysisCache.java:369)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getMethodAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:322)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ClassContext.getMethodAnalysis(ClassContext.java:1002)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ClassContext.getMethodAnalysisNoException(ClassContext.java:976)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ClassContext.getMethodGen(ClassContext.java:287)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.FindUseOfNonSerializableValue.analyzeMethod(FindUseOfNonSerializableValue.java:126)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.FindUseOfNonSerializableValue.visitClassContext(FindUseOfNonSerializableValue.java:94)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DetectorToDetector2Adapter.visitClass(DetectorToDetector2Adapter.java:76)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.analyzeApplication(FindBugs2.java:1089)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:283)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs.runMain(FindBugs.java:402)
    edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.main(FindBugs2.java:1200)
```

This exception is getting from CI server and if I run findbugs localy, but if I run findBugs from Idea - everything is fine.

I found [this bugreport](https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1415/), but on current project we use `javac` copiler and new code doesn't have any lambda stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But there could be still compiler version (jdk version) issue.
Are there any difference in JDK versions on the CI and you local PC? 
You can try to reproduce the issue adding another one JDK at your local PC and running findbugs.